# Save as blob takes too long to download the file from given url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, blob, save-as

I have written the following service to save file from given URL.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('SOME_APP')
        .service("downloadService", downloadService);

        function downloadService($http){

            var downloadFileFromUrl = downloadFileFromUrl;

            function downloadFileFromUrl(url){

                if(!url.length){
                    //TO-DO handle the error
                }

                else{
                    //find the file name and extension, to save it as:
                    var fileName;
                    for(var i=url.length; i>=0; i--){
                        if(url[i]=='/'){
                            fileName=url.slice(i+1, url.length);
                            console.log(fileName);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $http({
                        url: url,
                        method: "GET",
                        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                        }).success(function (data) {
                            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: '*/*'});
                            saveAs(blob, fileName);
                        }).error(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            //TO-DO error handling
                    });
                }
            }

            return {
                    downloadFileFromUrl : downloadFileFromUrl
            }
        }
}());
```

When I call the service, service first downloads the file, once the download is completed, then it shows the download in the browser (with progress as 100%). How do I make it work normally? (initiate the download in browser, and show the progress gradually)

Comment: why not set a timer?

Comment: You cannot have both. You cannot have the native browser download and get a progress notification. You would need to setup a regular XmlHttpRequest and add an progress listener, or find a way to manipulate the underlying XHR object in `$http` in order to add a listener.

Comment: you are saving it every time data comes that is not the best way to download. It is better to register for the event for incoming data and know when completes the transaction. If you want it a simple as a download you can provide a link to a tag html and give download attribute to it. That simply downloads it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to download a file from the given url. I implemented it using HTML5 anchor tag with download attribute as:

In index.html:

```
               <a id='downloadTag' href="" download hidden></a>
```

And in service:

```
                document.getElementById("downloadTag").href=url;
                document.getElementById("downloadTag").click();
```

This solved my problem.